# wkhtmltopdf - Missing url and output file arguments

Tags: python, flask, wkhtmltopdf

I'm trying to create a PDF using wkhtmltopdf and am failing at do so, I am for now using a really basic example, but that gives me out the exception:

`Exception: Missing url and output file arguments`

Here is the full screenshot of the page:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/207311432/Exception%20%20Missing%20url%20and%20output%20file%20arguments%20%20%20%20Werkzeug%20Debugger.png

And here is my code

```
from app import app 
from wkhtmltopdf import wkhtmltopdf

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Working!'

@app.route('/pdf')
def pdf_gen():
    wkhtmltopdf(url='http://www.example.com', output_file='/home/jsmith/pypdf/example.pdf')
    return 'PDFing'
```

I'm using flask web app to generate it.

Thanks!